# Ошибка Not a statement в java

Tags: java

вот такая вот проблема
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
я правда не понимаю что тут не так

Comment: я извеняюсь, если я задал такойже вопрос, который уже решили

Comment: просто уже 2 минуты сижу не понимаю

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Целых две минуты!*

За это время можно было найти десять примеров объявления и инициализации массива строк в Java.

---

```
    String[] inter = {"aaa", "bbb"};
```

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: @serverexe Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: поставил. извените за задержку, хотел поставить сразу же, но нужно было ждать 2 минуты, потом забыл